# React Redux counter example from Egghead videos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just ran into an issue while working on Dan's redux course on Egghead videos. When the action is dispatched, ReactDOM render doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts?
I'm not able to figure out exactly what is missing.

Here is the link to code snippet: http://jsbin.com/medogul/10/edit?html,js,output

```js
const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1;
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const Counter = ({
  value,
  onDecrement,
  onIncrement
}) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{value}</h1>
    <button onClick={onIncrement}> + </button>
    <button onClick={onDecrement}> - </button>
  </div>
);

const { createStore } = Redux;

// specify store with the reducer
const store = createStore(counter);

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter value={store.getState()} 
    onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'})}
    onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({type:'DECREMENT'})}
    />
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 small issues in your code:

1. You shouldn't pass the getState function to the component, but to pass the value returned by its call: `<Counter value={store.getState()}`
2. You ommited the comma in the React.render function:

   ```
   <Counter value={store.getState()} 
            onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'})}
            onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({type:'DECREMENT'})}
   />, // here must be a comma added
   document.getElementById('root')
   ```

Fixed version on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/puqiwilixa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: A quick follow up question, I tried downloading the working code from JSBin and running in Chrome but that doesn't work. Anything that I'm missing to get that part working?

Comment: That code is written with es6. The browser cannot execute it directly but it must be converted using babel before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Counter value={store.getState()}
```

instead of `<Counter value={store.getState}`